# jQuery calling $.fn function from other file

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Hello i'm having an issue trying to read jQuery function from another file.

**misFunciones.js**

```
function formatString() {
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
return arguments[0].replace(/\{(\d+)\}/g, function (match, index) {
    return args[index];
});
}


jQuery.fn.soloNumerosDecimales = function () {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).keydown(function (e) {
            var key = e.charCode || e.keyCode || 0;



            if (e.keyCode == 190 || e.keyCode == 110 || e.keyCode == 188) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $(this).val($(this).val() + ',');
            }


            return (
                (key == 65 || key == 86 || key == 67) && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true) ||
                key == 8 ||
                key == 9 ||
                key == 13 ||
                key == 46 ||
                key == 110 ||
                key == 190 ||
                (key >= 35 && key <= 40) ||
                (key >= 48 && key <= 57) ||
                (key >= 96 && key <= 105));
        });
    });
};
```

The function works perfect when are inside the same file, but when i try to call it from another .js file i get

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).soloNumerosDecimales is not a function
```

**Imports**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/event.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/cldr/supplemental.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/globalize.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/globalize/number.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.globalize.js"></script>
```

**Load cldr json**

```
<script>
    $.when(
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/likelySubtags.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/supplemental/numberingSystems.json"),
        $.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/numbers.json")
    ).then(function () {
        console.log("start slicing");
        return [].slice.apply(arguments, [0]).map(function (result) {
            console.log("slicing done");
            return result[0];
        });
    }).then(Globalize.load).then(function () {
        Globalize.locale("es-AR");
        console.log("Locale set to es-AR");
        }).then(console.log("LOADED EVERYTHING"));
</script>
```

**Adding script of misFunciones.js**

```
<script src="~/Scripts/misFunciones.js"></script>
```

**Trying to use it**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $("#ref_primaria_positivo").soloNumerosDecimales();
});
```

Thank you so much in advance and sory for my english :(

Comment: You have to include jQuery, then include your file that creates the method on the jQuery namespace, then have your logic that uses it.

Comment: @Taplar I already included jQuery, how can add the method on the jQuery namespace? Ty!

Comment: You are already doing that with your `$.fn.soloNumerosDecimales = function () {` logic.  jQuery just has to have been included before that point so `$` exists on the page as `jQuery` before you execute that logic.

Comment: What you have should work. It's likely not working due to when you define said function within `misFunciones.js`

Comment: do you mean to add it in the .js file?

Comment: i mean it depends on what the file contains. Your question, as it is currently, is unanswerable.

Comment: @KevinB the function works, the problem is when i put it in      misFunciones.js, then i cant use it anymore :S

Comment: where in `misFunciones.js`? Is that all `misFunciones.js` contains? nothing else?

Comment: misFunciones.js only contain this function, and i calling it from a .cshtml file where i imported jQuery

Comment: Then your path is likely incorrect. Use your dev tools. F12

Comment: You can utilize a bundler for the framework, which will create a globally accessible script for site wide access.  But I'd need more information to assist you.

Comment: It's weird because the jquery documentation shows the extensions set up differently --> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.fn.extend/

Comment: I add a simple function to misFunciones.js and i can use it whitout any problems, what information can i give you @Greg? Thanks!

Comment: @JuanSalvadorPortugal Is this web forms, mvc, etc.

Comment: i tryed using jQuery.fn instead of $.fn but the result is the same :S

Comment: @Greg Yes it's MVC 5, i'm not using Script Bundles because it have problems whit them and the globalize validators i'm using, so i add the scripts one by one

Comment: Please edit your question to show 1) the exact contents of  misFunciones.js, 2) the exact logic in the page where you are including jquery, including misFunctiones.js, and the logic trying to use it.

Comment: @Taplar and already edited the question, i add misFunciones.js and the other imports and js from .cshtml file!

Comment: @Greg i updated the post with more information.

Comment: I made it work by removing the Document.Ready, someone know how to make work inside it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was call the function before the document.ready function

```
  $("#ref_primaria_positivo").soloNumerosDecimales();
  $(document).ready(function () {
  )};
```

Thanks everyone!